# Why were algorithm names, which duplicate FP notions, reinvented

Tags: c++11, functional-programming, naming-conventions, language-lawyer

These algorithms seem to correspond one on one with common notions in functional programming:

```
std::transform - map
std::remove_if - filter
std::accumulate - foldr
```

Why did the committee decide to introduce new names for already established actions (as of 2011)? References to the technical proposals?

Comment: Perhaps they didn't know these functional programming notions? I've never heard of `foldr`, and frankly, that just looks stupid. Another good reason is that `std::map` already existed.

Comment: @CodyGray zero chance the committee members were not acquainted to those notions. There were a multitude of mature functional languages in 2011, like Python. For sure it was a conscious decision.

Comment: Why do you assume, with 100% certainty, that people who sit on the C++ language committee are also experts in the Python programming language?

Comment: @CodyGray 1) Python is a popular language 2) `map` and `filter` are built-ins (no need to be expert or intermediate user of the language) 3) the committee is large 4) those guys are not average Joe-s 5) Python is an integral part of most Linux distributions 6) someone designing a language aught to know at least 1-2 others.

Comment: Interestingly [C++17 is introducing "fold expressions"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nhk8pF_SlTk&index=21&list=PLs3KjaCtOwSZ2tbuV1hx8Xz-rFZTan2J1). Hooray, templates are not dead yet.

Comment: Hooray, C++'s syntax finds new ways to get more complicated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `std::map` is already taken by a [container](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)
2. `std::remove_if` is not a single function - there's a set of similar functions: [`std::remove`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/), [`std::remove_copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_copy/), [`std::remove_copy_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_copy_if/). It would be really strange to have `filter` instead of `remove_if` in this set.
3. I can't really tell anything about accumulate and foldr, but from my opinion standard library names tend to be non-shortened for a clarity purpose and foldr is not very clear name.

Comment: the [Fold (higher-order function)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) is pretty common in a lot of languages. `foldr` ("fold right") is a lot clearer (to me) than `accumulate` because it tells you the order the elements are folded in – in contrast to `foldl` ("fold left")